# SQL Beginner: Using SELECT correctly in my first SQL Project

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to get the statements to read as followed:

1. Customer "Gerald" bought 3 copes of "Thick as a Brick"
2. Customer "Joe" bought 12 copies of "Dustbowl"

My error:

```
SELECT MAX(version) 
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` 
WHERE `db_name` = 'CD'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'pma'@'localhost' for table 'pma__tracking'

My Code:

```
CREATE DATABASE CD;
USE CD;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CDS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customers;

CREATE TABLE CDS (
    CDId INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CDTitle VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    CDPrice FLOAT(7,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CDId)
    CONSTRAINT FK_Borrower 
        FOREIGN KEY (BorrowerId) 
        REFERENCES Customers(CustomersId)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomersId UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CustomersName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Copies INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CustomersId)
);

INSERT INTO CDS VALUES (null, "Thick As A Brick", 2.50);
INSERT INTO CDS VALUES (null, "Dustbowl", 2.00);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (null, "Gerald", 3);
SET @gerald := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (null, "Joe", 12);
SET @joe := LAST_INSERT_ID();

SELECT * FROM Customers, CDS from CDS.Borrower;
```

Not at all sure how to use Select and have tried a hundred different variants of it to get anything to show up. Any help would be great!!!!

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the user `pma` hasn't been granted `SELECT` permission to the table.

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the configuration of phpMyAdmin, not a problem in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
command denied to user 'pma'@'localhost' for table 'pma__tracking'
```

This looks more like a permission issue than an error in your statement.

Make sure that the user pma has all the needed permissions.